# popstate event handler seems not to work

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with a 'popstate' event handler, this is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event){
    if (event.state) {
        alert('abc')
    }
});

// The data object is arbitrary and is passed with the popstate event.
var dataObject = {
    createdAt: '2011-10-10',
    author: 'donnamoss'
};

var url = '/posts/new-url';
history.pushState(dataObject, document.title, url);
```

I expected this code will pop up an alert box when it's executed but, nothing happens.

Is there anything wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Testing the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/Lrf62/), the `.pushState()` event seems to fail. Replacing the variables with strings allowed me to fire the event.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - This only means `pushState` returns `false` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`pushState` do not trigger the `popstate` event, only clicking back / forward button (or use backspace) or invoking `history.back()` / `history.go(n)` would trigger this event.

Also, in webkit browsers, a `popstate` event would be triggered after page's `onload` event, but Firefox and IE do not have this behavior.

Comment: The popstate event mentioned earlier is triggered when the page is loaded or when
history.pushState() is called. In the case of the latter, the event object will contain a
state property that holds the data object given to history.pushState(). Can you check this, plz, I quoted from Javascript Web Application?

Comment: I read [HTML standards](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) and did not find any step triggering the `popstate` event. I was doing a history api related topic yestertoday and I'm sure `pushState` do not fire any `popstate` events. Isn't it weird if a **push** action triggers a **pop** event? if a **push** triggers a **pop**, than what would be left in the history stack? nothing?

Comment: Now I borrowed one Javascript Web Application book from my friend, yes it says `pushState()` would trigger `popstate` event, but I think it is an error of this book, no other resource on the web confirms such behavior.

Comment: Thanks so much otakustay, I could have been chosen Derek for his quick reply, but finally picked your answer due to your enthusiasm in answering my question. Thank you.

Comment: This can be strange for users migrating from History.js (do you remember!?), where the `statechange` event was always fired...

Answer (score 7):

No it will not,

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/popstate)

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript).

Again as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195502/chrome-onpopstate-pushstate-bug) the `popstate` event is not triggered in `Chrome` when you call `pushState()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) will not trigger the [`popstate`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-popstate) event by definition.

> The popstate event is fired in certain cases when navigating to a session history entry.

This event is intended to be only triggered when navigating to a history entry, either by pressing the back/forward button, or `history.go/back`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are infact calling pushState, then check if the page has iframes anywhere.

Rendering an iframe, then setting the `src` of the iframe using Javascript, will create a history entry. However, pressing the back button will NOT trigger the top level popstate listener. Because instead it is triggering the popstate inside of the iframe. To a user, they might click the back button and see nothing happen. So technically, yes, popstate listener isn't being triggered. Unfortunately this is intended behavior.