# Internet Explorer 10 and popstate not binding

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10

I was wondering what could cause `window.addEventListner('popstate', foo, false) window.attachEvent('onpopstate', foo)` and `window.onpopstate=foo` to not trigger the function foo. We have code similar to this and in production it does not fire but in development it does. Is it possible to disable the popstate event via JS or cause some sort of collision or race condition for this to occur?

#### EDIT ([Gustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504920/gustin)): + Sample Code

**PopStateEvent.js (complete listing, using jQuery 1.9.1):**

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function () { alert("Pop state event received!"); });
```

If I'm testing this very simple example with **IE 10** (10.0.9200.16484), I never receive a pop state event (i.e. the alert box never appears). Not even if I navigate away and come back via the back button of IE. I.e. [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112341/popstate-event-handler-seems-not-to-work) doesn't solve my case.

With **Chrome 24**, everything works fine.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the actual code. Do you have a link to the production site?

Comment: I have the EXACT same issue. Ever figure this one out?

Comment: Do not tag as JavaScript when it's blatantly clear it's a jQuery question.

Comment: @John: jQuery is simply a JavaScript libary.  What's wrong with tagging [tag:javascript]?  See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32446/should-jquery-questions-always-be-tagged-with-javascript) on when it's appropriate to tag jQuery questions with JavaScript.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Meta has never been constructive in my experience. This question was both asked and answered with jQuery not JavaScript. They are not one and the same due to the dependency on a framework so there is no reason to tag it as otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you aren't calling it using history.pushState() or history.replaceState()?

popstate is only triggered when you do something with the browser, like the back button , or called using history.back().

other than that, it will work with chrome because it'll shoot a popstate when the page is loaded, so check to make sure the event is actually being loaded.  Checking for this should be included in the :

```
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    initApplication();
}
```

I believe popstate is included in document.readyState, so give it a shot.