# Firefox not firing popstate event on forward

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, browser-history, html5-history

Working on ajax pages with History API. And stuck at the point where Firefox does not firing "popstate" event:

**Here's the visits flow (URLs):**

`1. Started from Home Page (/)
2. Visited About Us (/about-us)
3. Clicked Back Button to go on Home Page (/)
4. Refreshed the page using F5
5. Clicked Forward button to go on (/about-us) # Here firefox not firing "popstate" but Chrome is`

**The Script:**

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (e) {
    var data = window.history.state;
    console.log("State Data:");
    console.log(data);
    popped_first = true;
    ...
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112341/popstate-event-handler-seems-not-to-work

Comment: @ManishJangir So, according to this question. Firefox don't and won't fire popstate on forward/backward after reload page.

Answer (score 0):

Use pushState to wakeup it.

```
history.pushState({}, '');
window.onpopstate = function() {
    alert(1);
};
```