# Pressing backbutton on browser going back history url

Tags: php, jquery, html, browser-history

I am using

> window.history.pushState

and popstate functions for getting the previous page url's while clicking on back button of browser and i want to reload the page every popstate function calls.

My code is..

```
function refresh_results() {
    page_link = $("#form").serialize();
    if(page_link!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);

        }
}
```

In popstate function

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   var popped = ('state' in window.history && window.history.state !== null), initialURL = location.href;
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
            var initialPop = !popped && location.href == initialURL;
            popped = true;
            if (initialPop) return;
            pageurl = location;
            console.log(pageurl);
            window.location = location.href;
            //window.location = pageurl;
            return e.preventDefault();

        });
  }
});
```

But, for every time when i click on back button page is refreshing continuosly in chrome,but in firefox it's fine.
Can u suggest me how my functionlity will workable, and suggest me if i am missing anything

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195502/chrome-onpopstate-pushstate-bug